# Filled a battery with distilled water and trickle charged for days

Tags: battery, maintenance, charging

The starting voltage was 10.5 volts and when I left it charge at a 2Amp current it took a day to get to 11 volts and another day to get to 11.5 volts and would not go any higher.  I took it off charge for 8 hours and tested the voltage and it was back to 10.5 volts.

Is there more that I can/should do to try to revive this battery or is it time for a new one?

Thanks!

Comment: Its bad, buy a new one.

Comment: Did you just top it up with distilled water or it was dry and you filled it completely? If the last, then you needed to use electrolyte... ie sulphuric acid at the correct strength... but replace now...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  I topped it up but I didn’t check the specific gravity.  I took it to a parts store and they had a machine that tested the battery and agreed with Moab, the battery needed to be replaced.